# SAS: Toggle DM commands when running in batch mode

Tags: sas

I am using SAS 9.4 for Windows 7.  When I run anything in batch mode, such as [SASUnit](https://sourceforge.net/projects/sasunit/), I get a dialog stating

> This window is unavailable in line-mode.

My `AUTOEXEC.sas` contains these two lines which open the work library and maximize the IDE window:

```
dm 'dmsexp; expand libraries; expand work;';
dm 'awsmaximize on';
```

The error happens because there is no windowing environment when run in batch.  The `dm` statements don't apply.

It seems like the obvious solution, i.e. test whether SAS is running in batch mode or not, doesn't apply on Windows.  The [SYSENV](http://SYSENV) variable "reports whether SAS is running interactively."  Yet [on Windows](https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/hostwin/63285/HTML/default/viewer.htm#automacrovar.htm), `SYSENV` always contains the value `FORE`, the value which indicates "when you run SAS interactively through a windowing environment".

Is there a workaround for this other than opening my `AUTOEXE.sas` and commenting out those two lines *every* time I need to run something in batch?  Maybe there is command-line switch, such as `--no-init-file` for Emacs, which skips running `AUTOEXEC.sas`?

Comment: There is `-noautoexec` command line option if you want to use that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to know whether or not you can use Display Manager commands just check if Display Manager is running or not.

```
%if DMS=%sysfunc(getoption(dms)) %then %do;
  dm 'dmsexp; expand libraries; expand work;';
  dm 'awsmaximize on';
%end;
```

Note starting with SAS 9.4M5 you could include this exact code in your autoexec.sas file without having to first wrap it into a macro.

If you are using an old version of SAS then you could use a data step with `call execute()` instead.

```
data _null_;
  if 'DMS'=getoption('dms') then call execute(
  "dm 'dmsexp; expand libraries; expand work';dm 'awsmaximize on';"
  );
run;
```

Comment: I tracked this down as the source of a bizarre bug.  If AUTOEXE.sas contains only the lines given in your response, then the Enhanced Editor opens to the WORK library and maximizes. Awesome. Yet, the following error occurs.  When using a new SAS session (which runs AUTOEXE.sas on opening), submitting `**;` throws an `ERROR 180-322: Statement is not valid or it is used out of proper order.`  The error only happens once.  Submitting `**;` again causes no error.  I was able to fix this by wrapping your response in a macro and calling it: `%macro SetIDEDefaults(); ... %mend; %SetIDEDefaults();`.

Comment: Rereading your post, I see that you say that it should be wrapped in a macro!  Thanks!

Comment: Starting with release SAS 9.4M5 you do not need to create a macro to run this type of simple %IF/%THEN/%DO/%END block of code.  If your version of SAS is older then yes you need to wrap that code in a macro and call the macro. Or use data step with call execute to conditionally run the code.

Answer (score 3):

Just use the `-noterminal` option when invoking SAS as a batch job.

https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/hostwin/69955/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p16esisc4nrd5sn1ps5l6u8f79k6.htm

Also :

> Note: The -NOSTATUSWIN option enables you to run SAS in batch mode so that no windows are displayed. You can add options such as -NOTERMINAL, -NOSPLASH, -NOSTATUSWIN, and -NOICON to prevent the windows from being displayed.

Answer (score 0):

The `dm` statement is doing it (inside the code). It got solved when I commented that `dm` statement.